# What is difference between the two arrays of shapes (4,) and (4, 1)

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I have coded this.

```
a=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(a.shape)
```

then result is this.

```
(4,)
```

so i have coded this.

```
a=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
print(a.shape)
```

then result is this.

```
(1, 4)
```

The only difference between the two codes is the presence of `[]`

What is difference between `(4,)` and `(1, 4)`??

These two are the same, right?

Comment: The first is 1d and the second 2d even if theres no additional data.

Answer (score 7):

The shape gives the dimensions of the array.

The first is a 1-Dimensional array of length 4. `(4,)`

The second is a 2-Dimensional array with 1 column who's length is 4. or `(1,4)`

Comment: thanks you! I thought all arrays must be two-dimension.
I thought "(4,)" was just a two-dimensional array with column 1